# How to change server in DNF

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to install a package with `dnf` command utility, and it freezes on downloading stage. I think, it's a server problem. How I can change a server, which `dnf` uses to download from?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

The server information is stored in the repo file:

`/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo`

and

`/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo`

just you need to comment out the mirror url, and uncomment the baseurl lines and run `dnf update`

Also you can add a new mirror from [here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/)

it's recommended to activate RPMfusin on your system with:

```
su
#type your root password
rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: It's obvious. I mean is there a hotkey or something like that to take a next server in the mirrorlist? BTW, dnf should resolve this problem itself. It's a bug, I think.

Comment: @GAD3R can you tell me please why is it recommended to activate RPMFusion and who recommend this?